# How well has Iran's nanotechnology industry developed and how much is it used for political goals?

Tags: iran, middle-east, technology

I read that Iran has companies in the [nanotechnology industry](https://web.archive.org/web/20061114070827/http://www.nanovip.com/nanotechnology-companies/iran) and has developed some degree of private industry around nanotech. How well has the nanotech industry of Iran developed and how much is it used for political goals??

Comment: This sound like more of an [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) question, or a modern technology question.

Comment: Maybe, but I thought it would fit more into politics since I am asking specifically about how the industry has developed in Iran and affects its economy, not necessarily the specifics on how nanotechnology works or the nanotech industry in general.

Comment: I voted to close this question cause it's not really about politics but as you know that everything in Iran is mixed with politics, I would throw an answer for you but probably this question would be closed soon.

Comment: It's pretty small.

Comment: @TylerMc - already provided answer makes quite a good connection with Iran's politics, so I have edited the question to be connected to politics. This should save it from being closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm originally from Iran but I live in the US and also I worked in nanotechnology research and industry for several years in Iran before coming to the US.

Unfortunately, my view is mostly negative. I would describe why.

It's really hard to describe it cause if you did not live in Iran at least for several years, you can't imagine what's going on there, but the big problem is nanotechnology is used by Islamic Republic regime as a propaganda tool to show that, they have something to say in comparison to western countries. Because of this propaganda machine that is developed based on nanotechnology (don't believe it, check it out here: http://en.nano.ir/), researchers are rewarded not based on developing something really useful for research and industry, which is obviously beyond the current technological stage of Iran (Iran has lots of basic issues in essential industries like steel industries but how you can be at the forefront of nanotechnology!), but just based on publishing something in the nanotechnology field to show that Islamic Republic as a whole entity is trying to make progress in cutting edge science and that's really effective on public view.

So, you asked about profit. It's doesn't have any apparent profit for Islamic Republic or researchers but it just help them to maintain their current situation and that could be considered as one of the biggest benefits for the Islamic Republic and their supporters. What about the growth and research? Unfortunately, due to that heavily inferior technological situation of Iran in comparison to western countries, must of the published materials in the nanotechnology field is bogus and we should not blame the researchers, cause imagine: if you don't have any fund and any instrument, but you are forced to publish something in order to get graduated, you don't have any choice to fake some data and just move on and you need to be really an ethical person to just leave the system, which sadly is really rare these days. Honestly nobody cares that much about what did you published and even if it could be used for something in the real world at all or not, because the basic use of the whole nanotechnology showcase is just for propaganda. It's sad but it's mostly true...